# zoom changes slider behavior css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I have created a circle slider using JavaScript, and I need it to act right if it gets zoomed in or out.

My issue is when the circle slider gets zoomed in eg. (zoom: 0.5) , the mouse event listener for the slider will not act probably.

This issue only happen if I set the the zoom property to less or bigger than 1 .

You can try and see the differences: https://jsfiddle.net/mqgfxkjf/8/

Change:

```
<div style="zoom: 1.0">
```

To:

```
<div style="zoom: 0.5">
```

And you will find that it's not acting right while moving the slider to all-directions.

Tested on Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to scale the mouse position accordingly to the zoom value.

Let's say you have set zoom value to `0.5`, you will have to scale the mouse position (x and y) with the same value. So in order to fix this exact problem, you can do something as simple as just dividing by the scale value: `var mPos = {x: (e.clientX / 0.5) - elPos.x, y: (e.clientY / 0.5) - elPos.y };`.

I highly suggest that you let the script handle the scale / zoom value so that you can set it as a variable in your script. I.e. something like this:

```
(function () {
            var scaleValue = 0.5;

    addZoom(scaleValue);

    var $container = $('#container');
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var sliderW2 = $slider.width()/2;
    var sliderH2 = $slider.height()/2;    
    var radius = 200;
    var deg = 0;    
    var elP = $('#container').offset();
    var elPos = { x: elP.left, y: elP.top};
    var X = 0, Y = 0;
    var mdown = false;
    $('#container')
    .mousedown(function (e) { mdown = true; })
    .mouseup(function (e) { mdown = false; })
    .mousemove(function (e) {
        if (mdown) {
           var mPos = {x: (e.clientX / scaleValue) - elPos.x, y: (e.clientY / scaleValue) - elPos.y };
           var atan = Math.atan2(mPos.x-radius, mPos.y-radius);
           deg = -atan/(Math.PI/180) + 180; // final (0-360 positive) degrees from mouse position 

           X = Math.round(radius* Math.sin(deg*Math.PI/180));    
           Y = Math.round(radius*  -Math.cos(deg*Math.PI/180));
           $slider.css({ left: X+radius-sliderW2, top: Y+radius-sliderH2 });              
           // AND FINALLY apply exact degrees to ball rotation
           $slider.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'});
           $slider.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'});
           //
           // PRINT DEGREES               
           $('#value').html('angle deg= '+deg); 
        }
    });
})();

function addZoom(scaleValue) {
  $('#zoom-container').css('zoom', scaleValue);
}
```

Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/mqgfxkjf/10/

Comment: You just saved me 3 days of long testing and research. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help! I've recently been working on a similar task, so I noticed your problem fairly quick! :P

Comment: just to make it perfect , add scaleValue instead of 0.5 . var mPos = {x: (e.clientX / scaleValue) - elPos.x, y: (e.clientY / scaleValue) - elPos.y };

Comment: My bad! Updated fiddle and example now. The pain of copy/pasting code! :P